# let $f(x)$ be uneven and $f(x) = x(\pi - x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ prove the following:

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

let $f(x)$ be uneven and $f(x) = x(\pi - x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ prove the following:

> If $||f||_{L_2[-\pi,\pi]}^2 = \frac{\pi^4}{30}$, calculate $\sum \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^6$ and also $\sum \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^6$.

I thin i need to use parseval's theorem using the following orthonormal base:

$$E = \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(nx), \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(nx)\}$$

calculating $(e_i, f(x))$ is kind of troublesome...

Is there an easier way to find the solution?

Kees

Comment: $f(x)$ as you defined is uneven the title seems to either miss some information or includes more info than needed ...

Comment: it includes more info then needed, i edited it out :)

Comment: You might want to define $\tilde{f}$ in terms of $f$ to be an even function which is defined on $[-\pi,\pi]$. It is even, hence its Fourier series contains only $\cos(nx)$ terms. Also, what is your definition of $\langle f,g \rangle$ over $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: What is troublesome about computing the Fourier coefficients? Just integrate by parts.

Comment: @Your ad Here, it takes a lot of time computing (e_i,f) for the uneven and even part. So you need to integrate 6 different functions and it takes a lot of time. 

I Am trying to see smart little things so one can already say that some integrands will be 0 so one can compute, for example 2 integrands instead of 6.

Comment: One thing you could do is compute sine and cosine terms simultanously using Euler's identity. I.e. compute $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{inx} dx$.